# NPM Scripts: Pass one script command json output to another script command as argument value

Tags: javascript, git-bash, npm-scripts, codeceptjs

I am trying to inject a json as an argument value within npm script, like this:
(https://medium.com/typeforms-engineering-blog/codeceptjs-puppeteer-setting-up-multiple-configurations-32d95e65adf2)

```
"scripts": {
        "example": "bash -c 'cat ./sample.json | tr -d ' \t\n\r''",
        "test:override": "codeceptjs run --steps --config ./codecept.conf.js --override <expecting_output_json_here_from_example_script>",
    }
```

The first script command 'example' executes well and displays the output json correctly in the console (same as input):

```json
 {
   "helpers":{
   "Puppeteer":{
     "url":"http://yahoo.com",
     "show":false,
     "windowSize":"1920x1080"
   }
 }
```

however, I couldn't find the way to pass it as an argument value for the `--override` in the `"test:override"` script

I have tried various StackOverflow questions/answers, however, I couldn't find a way to achieve it.

I am using Git Bash in VS Code in Win10.

Please suggest a solution/alternate approach or point me to the right document/SO question.

To the best of my knowledge and efforts, I believe that it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Did you try ```"test:override": "codeceptjs run --steps --config ./codecept.conf.js --override $(npm run example)"```?

Comment: hi @edemaine, yes, tried that one already, however, the script just fails with JSON error, saying '$' at line 0

Comment: How about `"test:override": "bash -c 'codeceptjs run --steps --config ./codecept.conf.js --override $(npm run example)'"`